# "NOT IN" SQL across 2 oracle databases

Tags: sql

I have 2 Oracle databases A & B. I connect to A and run following SQLs:

1. `SELECT * FROM employee` has 2000 rows.
2. `SELECT empId FROM B.xx` has 700 rows.
3. `SELECT * FROM employee ​WHERE empId IN (SELECT empId FROM B.xx)` has 698 rows.
4. `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empId NOT IN (SELECT empId FROM B.xx)` return nothing!!!

I don't know why the last SQL didn't return anything. Is it because of "cross database"?
I can't re-produce this if I replace B.xx to another table in A.

Comment: To be sure I would add table aliases `..IN (SELECT bx.empId FROM B.xx bx)`

Comment: Actually my column name in A.employee and B.xx are not the same, I change them in the post just for easy reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` does not behave as expected if *any* of the results returned by the subquery are `NULL`.  As you observe, it returns no rows at all.

For this reason, I strongly recommend always using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B.xx x WHERE x.empId = e.empId);
```

Although you can fix the problem by adding a `WHERE x.empId IS NOT NULL`, I think that is a dangerous habit.  Sometime you are likely to leave out the `WHERE` clause and mistakenly think that there are no mismatches (yes, this has happened to me).  This cannot happen if you always use `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 3):

The most probable reason is that empId has NULL values in the table B.xx.
Try to run

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empId NOT IN (SELECT empId FROM B.xx where empId is not NULL)
```

this will give you a valid count.

That's just how not in works.